# I am trying to run my first c++ program and am getting this error:

Tags: c++, g++, fatal-error, wchar

c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\cwchar:44:10: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory  `#include <wchar.h>`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Did you try [#include <cwchar>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cwchar) instead of `#include <wchar.h>` which is a C (not C++) header?

Comment: Can you show us your code? How exactly do you compile it?